# Using condition to split pandas column of lists into multiple columns.

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataFrame with two columns that looks like the following:

```
d1 = {'Time1': [[93, 109, 187],[159],[94, 96, 154, 169]],
              'Time2':[[16, 48, 66, 128],[123, 136],[40,177,192]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

I need to split these columns of lists into 4 columns named 1st_half_T1, 2nd_half_T1, 1st_half_T2 and 2nd_half_T2 using pandas. The condition is, Time1 splits into 1st_half if `Time <= 96` and 2nd_half if `Time > 96` and applying the same condition to `Time2` gives the following output.

```
  1st_half_T1           2nd_half_T1     1st_half_T2      2nd_half_T2
0       [93]             [109, 187]    [16, 48, 66]           [128]
1         []                  [159]              []      [123, 126]
2   [94, 96]             [154, 169]            [40]      [177, 192]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` with a custom function

```
def my_split(row):
    return pd.Series({
        '1st_half_T1': [i for i in row.Time1 if i <= 96],
        '2nd_half_T1': [i for i in row.Time1 if i > 96],
        '1st_half_T2': [i for i in row.Time2 if i <= 96],
        '2nd_half_T2': [i for i in row.Time2 if i > 96]
    })
df.apply(my_split, axis=1)

Out[]:
  1st_half_T1   1st_half_T2 2nd_half_T1 2nd_half_T2
0        [93]  [16, 48, 66]  [109, 187]       [128]
1          []            []       [159]  [123, 136]
2    [94, 96]          [40]  [154, 169]  [177, 192]
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehensions with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
t11 = [[y for y in x if y <=96] for x in df['Time1']]
t12 = [[y for y in x if y >96] for x in df['Time1']]

t21 = [[y for y in x if y <=96] for x in df['Time2']]
t22 = [[y for y in x if y >96] for x in df['Time2']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'1st_half_T1':t11, '2nd_half_T1':t12,'1st_half_T2':t21, '2nd_half_T2':t22})
print (df)
  1st_half_T1 2nd_half_T1   1st_half_T2 2nd_half_T2
0        [93]  [109, 187]  [16, 48, 66]       [128]
1          []       [159]            []  [123, 136]
2    [94, 96]  [154, 169]          [40]  [177, 192]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

df_new.loc[:,'1st_half_T1'] = df['Time1'].apply(lambda x : [y for y in x if y <=96])
df_new.loc[:,'2nd_half_T1'] = df['Time1'].apply(lambda x : [y for y in x if y >96])
df_new.loc[:,'1st_half_T2'] = df['Time2'].apply(lambda x : [y for y in x if y <=96])
df_new.loc[:,'2nd_half_T2'] = df['Time2'].apply(lambda x : [y for y in x if y >96])
df_new
Out[64]: 
  1st_half_T1 2nd_half_T1   1st_half_T2 2nd_half_T2
0        [93]  [109, 187]  [16, 48, 66]       [128]
1          []       [159]            []  [123, 136]
2    [94, 96]  [154, 169]          [40]  [177, 192]
```